# Reporting Services Quarterly Schedule instead running Monthly

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in **SSRS 2012** scheduled to run quarterly on a specific day i.e. `15th Jan, 15th Apr, 15th Jul & 15th Oct`.

My shared schedule config is: `Ticked 'Month', selected Jan, Apr, Jul & Oct, set 'On calendar day(s)' to '15'.`

The schedule is displayed correctly but in fact runs on the `15th` of each month.

Knowing these schedules are actually implemented using SQL Server Agent I inspect the job and find that the job in question has 4 schedules against it.

```
15th day of every 12 month starting on the 1 jan 2013
15th day of every 12 month starting on the 1 apr 2013
15th day of every 12 month starting on the 1 jul 2013
15th day of every 12 month starting on the 1 oct 2013
```

so that also makes sense.

Is there a fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem (and solution) is the same as described here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/System-Center-Blog/Support-Tip-Scheduled-backup-to-tape-runs-on-a-wrong-date-on-DPM/ba-p/347075