# SSRS - Quarterly subscription running monthly instead on the specific schedule

Tags: reporting-services

I have a  quarterly subscription SSRS report and is scheduled to run  as follows

• November – January - report to be sent February 1st
• February – April - report to be sent May 1st
• May – July - report to be sent August 1st
• August – October - report to be sent November 1st

The report is generated on every month instead of above schedule.  Recreated the subscription but no luck.

Created stored procedure as below.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetQuarterlydateinfo 
 AS    

 SET NOCOUNT ON ; 

SELECT  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,getdate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
            CONVERT(char(10), getdate(), 101)  AS CurrentDate, 
    CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) =  2 THEN 'Q1'
                                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) =  5 THEN 'Q2'
                                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) =  8 THEN 'Q3'
                                WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) =  11 THEN 'Q4'
        ELSE 0
        END As CurrentQuarter

    RETURN 
GO
```

Is there any way that i can use the above stored procedure and use those days to schedule the report.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SS Reporting Services Quarterly Schedule instead running Monthly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305457/ss-reporting-services-quarterly-schedule-instead-running-monthly)

Comment: Dale - Before posting a question  i checked that one . Is there any other way ?

Comment: Yip - write your own scheduler :)

Comment: Dale - you mean make changes in the SQL Server Agent Job?

Comment: The link explains what you need to do to the agent job to get it working. But you asked for another way, and the other way is to write your own app/service which does the scheduling for you.

Comment: Dale - Is it possible for you to explain clearly with updated  stored procedure in my question  with what you are doing in the link you referred, there are so many parameters i want to make it simple.

Comment: sorry I don't have time - as you say its complicated

Comment: Maybe try setting the start date of the sql agent job to the next date you want the report to run - that may reset the schedule and get it back on track.

Comment: I will try that option. Thanks, Dale